# Non-ASCII characters being passed from Robot Framework to Powershell display as question marks

Tags: powershell, utf-8, robotframework

I have a suite of tests in robot Framework that call Powershell scripts with a "username" parameter. This is fine until the username contains a non-ASCII (non-English) in this case character. Robot is outputting the character correctly (I have checked by logging the value and also writing a text file with the value, and they are always correct).

But when it reaches the Powershell script, the username only displays a line of question marks instead.

I know this is something to do with the text encoding, but can't figure out if/how there's any way to deal with it.

A workaround option I have is to write the username out of Robot to a temporary text file and then get the Powershell script to read that value from the text file. This works successfully, but is pretty inefficient when running lots of these scripts on multiple machines.

The test suite I have is as follows (only the salient lines pulled out):

```
*** Variables ***
${user_name}    ÀÀÀ

*** Test Cases ***
Write foreign username
    Write Username    ${user_name}

*** Keywords ***
Write Username 
    [Arguments]    ${user_name}
    Run    powershell.exe -file ".\\..\\Powershell\Write-Username.ps1" -UserName "${user_name}"
```

The Powershell script then contains the following code:

```
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$UserName
)

$username | Out-File C:\Temp\Test.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: without the script hard to guess. First in mind comes `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding`

Answer (score 0):

From [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html):

> **Output encoding**
>
> All output files are written using `UTF-8` encoding. Outputs written
>   to the console use the **current console encoding**.

Robot Framework is a Python-based; therefore, next **Python example** could exemplify the case:

```
import sys
username = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅ'
print( sys.stdout.encoding, "username=" + username)
```

**Output** (showing `?` question marks for variety of particular console encoding) leads to next **corollary**: set active console to proper encoding before starting *Robot Framework*; the best choice could be `utf-8`; see [Change the active console Code Page](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html), use `CHCP 65001` ([Windows `cmd`](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8#comment1254140_685264)).

```
==> D:\test\Python\38975403.py
utf-8 username=ÀÁÂÃÄÅ

==> chcp 1252 >NUL

==> python D:\test\Python\38975403.py
cp1252 username=ÀÁÂÃÄÅ

==> chcp 850 >NUL

==> python D:\test\Python\38975403.py
cp850 username=ÀÁÂÃÄÅ

==> chcp 437 >NUL

==> python D:\test\Python\38975403.py
cp437 username=????ÄÅ

==> chcp 852 >NUL

==> python D:\test\Python\38975403.py
cp852 username=?ÁÂ?Ä?
```

FYI, there are used next *out-of-ASCII* letters in above example:

```
Ch UniCode     Dec    UTF-8    Comment

 À  U+00C0     192    0xC380   Latin Capital Letter A With Grave
 Á  U+00C1     193    0xC381   Latin Capital Letter A With Acute
 Â  U+00C2     194    0xC382   Latin Capital Letter A With Circumflex
 Ã  U+00C3     195    0xC383   Latin Capital Letter A With Tilde
 Ä  U+00C4     196    0xC384   Latin Capital Letter A With Diaeresis
 Å  U+00C5     197    0xC385   Latin Capital Letter A With Ring Above
```